# How can I include the cs50.h file?

Tags: c, cs50

I try to use #include <cs50.h> but it's not work, so I try to fix it by this solution.

This is the comment that I found to fix my problem but it's not work for me:

> I was able to get mine working on my Mac with Visual Studio Code as
> follow: Assuming you have Visual Studio already installed and with all
> C/C++ extensions required for compiling and running C codes,
>
> 1a. Download the CS50 Library from
> https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/releases
>
> 1b. Extract/unzip the downloaded zipped folder
>
> 2a. Open Terminal and change directory to the unzipped CS50 library
> folder. For example if folder is on desktop and the folder is named
> libcs50-10.1.0 , then terminal command should be: cd
> desktop/libcs50-10.1.0
>
> 2b. Still in terminal after changing directory, then run the command:
> sudo make install
>
> 3a. After installation, close terminal, go to visual studio and write
> your C program
> #include <cs50.h>
>
> 3b. Link cs50 when compiling your code with clang. Example if your
> file name is hello.c clang hello.c -o hello -lcs50
>
> 4a. run your code

After I follow in step 2a. my terminal say

`cd: no such file or directory: desktop/libcs50-11.0.2`

Please help me to fix this problem, thank you.

Comment: Are you working on a Mac?  If not, which o/s are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler., Yes, on mac.

Comment: When you did step 1a, where did you save the file?  Was the name `libcs50-11.0.2.zip`?  Step 1b requires you to know where you saved the file (well, I suppose there probably is a way to unzip from in the browser, but you're going to need to know where it was saved even so).  I'd use the terminal for step 1b too.  When you run `unzip libcs50-11.0.2.zip`, it will create a sub-directory `libcs50-11.0.2`.  I'd then use `cd libcs50-11.0.2` to find the source code.  On my machine, using `make install` would be sufficient — I own the sub-directories under `/usr/local`. You may need the `sudo` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command in the directory where you unzipped the folder. If you unzipped it in `Downloads`, run `cd Downloads`, then `cd libcs50-11.0.2`

Comment: I did it in desktop.

Comment: oh then i guess it's just a matter of capitalization. Try `cd Desktop/libcs50-11.0.2` instead of `cd desktop/libcs50-11.0.2`. Capitalization matters